# Next and previous ad function in the classifieds website

Tags: php, mysql

```
<script>(function(d, s, id) {var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];if (d.getElementById(id)) return;js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/lt_LT/all.js#xfbml=1";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);}(document,'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
<script type="text/javascript">  window.___gcfg = {lang: 'lt'}; (function() { var po = document.createElement('script');po.type = 'text/javascript'; po.async = true;po.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js';var s =document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);  })();</script>
```

Next and prev ad in classifieds system ed_classified?

Hi,

I am new in Drupal and I'm trying to build classifieds website. Right now I'm testing ed_classifieds project and it lacs one (in my view) big feature: links (or buttons) to the next and previous ad in same category.

For ex:

1. Classifieds are in categories (auto-moto, pets-animals, jobs-wanted, services, appliances and so on)
2. Categories can have other sub-categories inside (auto-moto >> auto, pets-animals >> dogs, jobs-wanted >> city_name etc.) and even deeper, without limiting depth.
3. When visitor clics on the ad link in ads list and is redirected to ad view page, with all the info he/she can see „next ad“ and „previous ad“ links/buttons. Ideally, there should be some extra info too (like ad title, country/city so on).

I saw this feature in this website http://www.parduodu-perku.lt, which I found on some joomla forum and I really liked that feature and want to implement it into my new website. Can someone help me?

Comment: Welcome to SO.  As you can see, Mike Brant formatted your code for you.  This makes it easier for the rest of the community to see what you're asking.  On future questions you can do this by highlighting the code and clicking on the curly braces.